# Css not working in asp.net c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I have three files `html`,`css`,`javascript`.My `css` not working.I don't know why??
Here is my aspx code :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
<form id="form" runat="server">
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" runat="server"></div>
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is StyleSheet.css

```
#editor {
width: 100px;
height: 500px;
background-color:#444;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: monospace;
display: block;
}
.statement {
color: #00FF00;
}
```

and here is JScript.js

```
$(function () {
$("div[ID$='editor']").on("keydown keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").trim();
        var word = text.split(" ");
        var newHTML = "";

        $.each(word, function (index, value) {
            switch (value.toUpperCase()) {
                case "SELECT":
                case "FROM":
                case "WHERE":
                case "LIKE":
                case "BETWEEN":
                case "NOT LIKE":
                case "FALSE":
                case "NULL":
                case "FROM":
                case "TRUE":
                case "NOT IN":
                    newHTML += "<span class='statement'>" + value + "&nbsp;</span>";
                    break;
                default:
                    newHTML += "<span class='other'>" + value + "&nbsp;</span>";
            }
        });

        $(this).html(newHTML);

        //// Set cursor postion to end of text
        var child = $(this).children();
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        $(this)[0].focus();
    }
  });
 });
```

and in Masterpage.master here is link of `StyleSheet.css` and `JScript.js`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript.js"></script>
```

`div` height,width,background color not changing.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's runat server the ID will be changed, change ClientIDMode to static to be predictable, but even better: add a CssClass to the control.

Comment: But `runat="Server" ` is compulsory because i wana use `div` text in code behind

Comment: Yes, but the ID will be different when it's generated to the client - look at the html source in your browser. During generation there will be things added to the ID - so it's no longer just "#ID". That's why you need to change to ClientIDMode="static"

Answer (score 0):

You have made div `runat="server"` which will change the `ID` of `div` accoriding to `ContentPlaceHolder` so `#editor` will not be found in page.

Either make a `class` in `css` and assign `class` to the `div` or set `ClientIDMode="static"` on `div` so its `id`  remains same as which you have set.

```
.editor {
width: 100px;
height: 500px;
background-color:#444;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: monospace;
display: block;
}

<div id="editor" calss="editor" contenteditable="true" runat="server"></div>
```

Or add `ClientIDMode="static` on `div`

```
<div id="editor" calss="editor" contenteditable="true" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="static"></div>
```

Comment: But `runat="Server" ` is compulsory because i wana use `div` text in code behind

Comment: yes i have not deleted that anyway you can make a calss in `css` and give that class to `div` see the anser.

Comment: Thanks it's working now.You great :) Can you tell me how can i get `div` text in code behind.I try this but it's not working `string cmd = editor.InnerText;TextBox1.Text = cmd;` it's only works when i do in this way `<div id="editor" calss="editor" contenteditable="true" runat="server">HELLO</div>` it return `HELLO`

Comment: sorry to say but it's retrieve `NULL` value.I use `String cmd=editor.InnerText`

Comment: Have you used `ClientIDMode="static` or have you given the class ?

Answer (score 0):

just put in div "clientidmode=Static" use below code

```
#editor {
 width: 100px;
 height: 500px;
 background-color:#444;
 color: white;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: monospace;
 display: block;
}

<div id="editor" clientidmode="Static" runat="server"></div>
```

try this . its working perfect for me

Comment: Can you tell me how can i get div text in code behind.I try this but it's not working `string cmd = editor.InnerText;TextBox1.Text = cmd; ` it's only works when i do in this way `<div id="editor" calss="editor" contenteditable="true" runat="server">HELLO</div> ` it return HELLO –

Comment: @Ashley you are coping your div content to `TextBox1` how it will work if there is no data inside that div you should add some data either manually or through code

Comment: @Ansari User enter sql query in `div` and press `button` then this inside the `div` text get in code behind.I waana do this

Comment: @Ashley how user will enter in div(it is not input field), user can input text in a textbox

Comment: @Ansari please check your email

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using `ClientIDMode` without adding this it will work no need to change your div just copy the below css:

Your div:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" runat="server">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

I also added rendered Div at the last

```css
 div[id$='editor'] {
      width: 100px;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: #444;
      color: white;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: monospace;
      display: block;
}
```

```html
<DIV id="ContentPlaceHolder1_editor" contentEditable="true">Lorem Ipsum</DIV>
```

Hope this will help you.